# need to pass value from javascript to Spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing encryption and decryption of message at javascript and want to send result message to the spring controller mvc.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/token")
public @ResponseBody String getAllBooks(@RequestParam boolean isAuth, @ModelAttribute("somedata") Token data) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("encryptedToken", data.getValue()); return token;}
```

Hence the token should hold the value from javascript. I am not using jquery. How to get that value from javascript to Spring mvc controller.

```
<script>
function Encrypt(msg) {
...................
...................
return encryptedFinally;}
</script>
```

I want to use this variable (i.e. encryptedFinally) in java controller class.

Comment: Post your Token code and also please make you question more clear

Comment: Java script has encrypted message the same I wan't to pass from Java script to Controller class method.

Comment: What about assemble token as a queryString in javascript?

Comment: How do you send this "/token" request? ajax or submit a form

Comment: I am sending token using submit a form.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a number of choices:

1. Add the variable into the Model object (you can follow the @WilQu suggestion for this)
2. Pass the variable asynchronously with AJAX
3. pass the variable as a URI parameter like so .../my/path/{var}/something/else/if/it/makes/sense
4. pass the variable as a query parameter like so /my/path?var=value

At first glance, for your problem I'd choose option number one.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input into your form and set the value of this input to the result of the encryption from your javascript code.